# Add SPA functionality with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, single-page-application, eleventy

I am using the following in my Eleventy site to add simple SPA functionality across the board.

```
  (function () {
    'use strict';
    var $ = function (sel, con) {
      return (con || document).querySelector(sel);
    };
    var nav = document.querySelector("#navbar");
    if (!nav) {
      console.warn('no navigation found.');
      return;
    }
    nav.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      var el = evt.target;
      var spa = el.getAttribute('data-spa');
      if (!!spa) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var href = el.getAttribute('href');
        var container = document.querySelector(spa);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
          var d = this.responseXML;
          var dTitle = d.title || '';
          var dContainer = document.querySelector(spa, d);
          container.innerHTML = (dContainer && dContainer.innerHTML) || '';
          history.pushState({}, dTitle, href);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', href);
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
        xhr.send();
      }
    });
  })();
```

How this should work is that `navbar` will not reload on link click however this does not work for some reason.

Would appreciate some help here.

Cheers.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Does nothing happen? Do you see an error in console?

Comment: No console error. An image is in the `navbar` and is reloaded when the event is fired (click on href). This code is meant to prevent `navbar` from refreshing when a new page is loaded.

Comment: Did you test that, for example, `spa`, is matched?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Are you sure this, `var spa = el.getAttribute('data-spa');`, is working?

Comment: It should be working..

Comment: Heh, well "should" does not imply it is. :) Can you try putting this online where we can see? Maybe via CodePen?